# Image max size according to parent's line-height

Tags: html, css

Is it possible with pure CSS to make an inline image size (scale) according to the line-height of its parent?

Consider this set-up:

HTML:

```
<p>
  <img src="image.png"/> text text text
</p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
  line-height: 16px;
}

img {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

What I would like is that the image gets scaled to a height of 16px, as is the `line-height` of the paragraph. Is this possible?

please note: I'm open to changes in the HTML and CSS, but I'm not after a JS solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no pure HTML/CSS way to do this, sadly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer even though this is not the answer I wanted to hear, but probably the right one. :) I still hope someone will add a solution. :)

Answer (score 6):

this works pretty well:

```
img {height: 1em;}
```

Comment: +1 However, the line-height could be (and often is) different from the height of the font. Your suggestion makes the image height equal to the font height. I consider your suggestion useful, but it doesn't answer my question completely. +1 for getting as close as possible though.

Comment: According to MDN, the default `line-height` is often about 1.2 so `1.2em` may be closer.  If you explicitly set the `line-height` then you can set this to the same value.

Comment: ... just realized..  the `img` is also subject to the `line-height` as it's an `inline-block` so setting the height to `1.2em` will make the whole line look taller.